# Why is this displaying Hello World when I run it?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.FlickrView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FlickrView extends Activity {

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            URL flickr = new URL("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=39350419@N06&lang=en-us&format=rss_200");
            URLConnection flickrConnect = flickr.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(flickrConnect.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            in.close();
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          System.out.println("Unable to load URL");
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you have Hello, World in your GUI files.  Look at `res/layout/main.xml` and `res/values/strings.xml`.  When you pass in `R.layout.main` (an int), the corresponding view is loaded from main.xml, which depends on strings.xml.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite sure because you have the default main.xml layout. In this default layout there is a TextView in a LinearLayout . The TextViews text is set to "Hello World, yourApplicationName".

You have to do something with your GUI in order to get anything displayed.

EDIT: System.out.println will redirect everything to your Android log. You can view the log using Logcat.